# The realm in the security database got changed accidently in MarkLogic. Now cannot Access admin interfaces

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I was restoring a database in MarkLogic and accidently I changed the security database also. Now I am not able to login into the admin interfaces using my previous admin username and password. I went through the documentation and came to know that if realm is changed in security database this can happen. But no solution was provided. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling MarkLogic but as this does not change the security database, I still could not login. I am sure that there must be a way to reset my login credentials but I couldn't find it. Can someone suggest what should I do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

- Stop MarkLogic
- Move all data
- Install a clean copy of MarkLogic
- Start MarkLogic

If you have a backup of the Security database, then restore that first. If not, recreate all security settings manually. After that, continue with:

- Recreate earlier databases with Forest names identical to how they were
- Stop MarkLogic
- Move back all Forest data except those of Security
- Start MarkLogic

You could try fiddling a bit with the XML configs like assignments.xml, but that is not highly recommended, and do make copies before you do so..

HTH!

Comment: I was able to run MarkLogic again. But i want my previous forests back on this installation.I tried what you said - Created new forests with the same name as previous, stopped marklogic server, Copied the data from my previous forests to the new one (Their were 5 folders in my original forest-0000002c,0000002d,Journals, Label,Large), Started marklogic server But now when I check the status of the forest using the admin console at port 8001, I get "This forest is unavailable while mounting." The size of the forests remains 0 MB and nothing happens. can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @vikas1092 What does ErrorLog.txt tell? You can find it under Data/Logs/

Comment: It is giving following error:
"2012-08-10 10:23:32.141 Alert: XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in startup of forest SeeDok
: SVC-MAPINI: Mapped file initialization error: open '/u01/forests/Forests/SeeDo
k/000000c8/Timestamps': Permission denied
"

Comment: Thanx grtjn
your answer was correct
However one more thing what we needed to do was to change the permissions of the forest after pasting it into the newly created forest. For now i changed it to 777 but we can give permission specific to the current marklogic user.